# Reject PDO MySQL statement if a specified value is found in a field?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, unique-constraint

I've searched Google but not had much luck with this, so maybe SO can help. I am developing a user authentication system for a couple of projects and need to ensure that the email address, which is also the username, is unique.

I set the field as unique in the MySQL query, but I need a way to cancel an SQL query and notify the user that "the specified email is already in use" if the supplied email matches an existing record.

I could do a select query before the insert, but I am wondering if there is a way to write the SQL query so that an insert is performed IF NOT EXISTS existing@example.com IN email or something like that.

Then if the insert is not performed, I need to know, and I need to be able to tell it apart from another error.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: You could just attempt the insert and catch the `PDOException` / check the MySQLi error for the appropriate code.

Comment: @Phil How can I make sure that the query failed specifically because of duplicate emails?

Comment: 1) run query to see if $email exists 2) if you get rows back, $email exists and you output the rejection stuff. if you get no rows back, it doesn't exist and you do whatever should happen then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PDO, you can just catch the exception and check the status code, eg

```
// make sure you're set to throw exceptions
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `user` (`email`) VALUES (?)');
try {
    $stmt->execute([$email]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo(); // apparently PDOException#getCode() is pretty useless
    if ($errorInfo[1] == 1586) {
        // inform user, throw a different exception, etc
    } else {
        throw $e; // a different error, let this exception carry on
    }        
}
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry_with_key_name

The process would be similar if using MySQLi

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `user` (`email`) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    if ($stmt->errno == 1586) {
        // inform user, throw a different exception, etc
    } else {
        throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer lets me. Thank you.

Comment: The error code may also be [1062](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry). I'd just try it out and see what error code you get back

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not getting any exception at all with my code. The insert fails, but there is no exception.

Comment: This fixed it: $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: `$e->getCode() returns the SQLSTATE not mysql error code. The SQLSTATE for 'integrity constraint violation' is 23000. After replacing 1062 with 23000 the code does what I want it to.

Comment: @Razick I was afraid that might happen. 23000 is a generic code. See my updated answer